# Fragment shader always uses 1.0 for alpha channel

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a 2d texture that I loaded with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, gs.width(), gs.height(), 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gs.buffer());
```

where `gs` is an object that with methods that return the proper types.

In the fragment shader I sample from the texture and attempt to use that as the alpha channel for the resultant color.  If I use the sampled value for other channels in the output texture it produces what I would expect.  Any value that I use for the alpha channel appears to be ignored, because it always draws `Color`.

I am clearing the screen using:

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?  I am getting an OpenGL 4.0 context with 8 red, 8 green, 8 blue, and 8 alpha bits.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;

void main()
{
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 Color;
in vec2 Texcoord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    float t = texture(tex, Texcoord);
    outColor = vec4(Color, t);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, I am surprised this actually works. `texture (...)` returns a `vec4` (unless you are using a shadow/integer sampler, which you are not). You ***really*** ought to be swizzling that texture down to just a single component if you intend to store it in a `float`.

I am guessing you want the alpha component of your texture, but who honestly knows -- try this instead:

```
float t = texture (tex, Texcoord).a; // Get the alpha channel of your texture
```

A half-way decent GLSL compiler would warn/error you for doing what you are trying to do right now. I suspect yours is as well, but you are not checking the shader info log when you compile your shader.

---

#### Update:

The original answer did not even begin to address the madness you are doing with your `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` internal format texture. I completely missed that because the code did not fit on screen.

Why are you using `gs.rgba()` to pass data to a texture whose internal and pixel transfer format is exactly 1 component? Also, if you intend to use a depth texture in your shader then the reason it is always returning **a=1.0** is actually ***very*** simple:

---

Beginning with GLSL 1.30, when sampled using `texture (...)`, depth textures are automatically setup to return the following `vec4`:

**vec4 (r, r, r, 1.0)**.

The **RGB** components are replaced with the value of **R** (the floating-point depth), and **A** is replaced with a constant value of **1.0**.

Comment: `rgba()` was my original name, when I was supplying those.  I changed the function, so that it only had a single component, but I forgot to change the function name to indicate that.  I have edited the post to change the name to `buffer()`.

Comment: @Graznarak: Well, if you want a non-1 value from a depth texture you are going to need to use the `.r` component. If you take the alpha component, as I discussed in the answer, it is always **1.0**.

Comment: I have changed the shader to use `float t = texture(tex, Texcoord).r;outColor = vec4(Color, t);` and it is still just outputting the color while apparently ignoring the fourth component.

Comment: @Graznarak: What exactly are you expecting this 4th component to do? Alpha by itself does next to nothing. Often times the framebuffer does not even have a place to store alpha values, so after the output alpha value has been used for blending, it pretty much ceases to exist. Your blend function is a pretty important part of this question.

Comment: I really just want it to blend the background color (black in this case) with `Color`.  So where `t` is 1.0 I get `Color` and where it is 0.0 I get black and some intermediate value if I am between the extremes.

Comment: @Graznarak: Then you need the following blend function: `glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`. And I do not see any part of your code that sets that up or that enables `GL_BLEND`. Without doing this, alpha has no impact on anything.

Comment: @Graznarak: That blend function will multiply the output color from your fragment shader by the output alpha and add it to the original color in your framebuffer by (1 - output alpha) from your fragment shader. It will do precisely what you want, but order-dependency may become an issue in more complicated rendering scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're only passing in a `vec3` when you need a `vec4`. RGBA - 4 components, not just three.

Comment: `Color` is a vec3, but `outColor` is a vec4.  What needs to have 4 components?